# Is this possible to copy Views fields declarations to another view?

Tags: 7, views, entities

Use case:

We have a page with a lot of complicated Views generating a lot of queries.
There is a way to do it in more efficient way but this needs a lot of changes in Views or even creating different views, similar in displays field declarations.

Is there any way to copy fields declarations between those views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try export view and look in export's code

Comment: Thanks, can be done in this way, but is too risky IMO

Comment: Risky? What do u mean?

Comment: It's not tested at all and error prone thing. I thought maybe script for this exists

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you want manually copy fields declarations - you can export view, make changes and import updated view from modified code. I don't know if there is automated solution with/without UI for making changes. So, exporting whole view manually can be the point.

Comment: I don't know any module for that, mb because view settings structure is pretty complicated and it's much easier to export view code and make changes manually as for me. And it's not much pros in making such module when base view's export exists. Oh, I remember there already were some modules for exporting many things, but it's not actually easy to make changes using them.